# Java App (with a broken sandbox) vs Web App

Tags: java, browser, applet, sandbox

My company and I are in the early planning stages of porting (or rewriting) a Java-based application to the web. It is a self-voicing SVG editor and viewer emphasizing accessibility. It is a mature project that is currently deployed as a Windows application only. It has several native dependencies (JNI):

- Windows Speech API (SAPI)
- custom device drivers (which fewer users take advantage of).

I have experimented with signed applets before and know I *can* access these native routines in the browser, if needed. But is that the right approach? **In my mind, shoehorning a full-featured Java application into the web browser is a mis-use of technology**. It would certainly not be a web app, in the traditional sense.

Given enough time, much of the application's functionality could be replicated with fairly simple HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. If the system were changed to a web-based client-server model, I could stream sound files, eliminating the SAPI dependency on the client end. Device drivers would be more tricky, but an invisible, scriptable Java applet may be justifiable in this instance.

I realize this is somewhat subjective, but I am looking for confirmation on the above assumptions. I see the web abandoning monolithic Java/Flash applications in favor of HTML+JavaScripted UIs. I am looking for the best "future-ready" and platform independent approach.

*(Moderators: flag as subjective, if needed)*

Comment: To make it platform independent, use a language that is a subset of all languages you know and have an automated source-converter. Or use something that will propably be supported for a long time, e.g. JS.

Comment: I experimented with Google's GWT which compiles Java code into JavaScript. This is really cool but seems very error-prone unless I start from scratch. In which case, I wouldn't gain much. I guess what I'm getting at is that I feel I should avoid embedding a highly complex Java-application in a browser like one avoids the plague. Is that valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When people write web apps in Java these days, the front end is typically (X)HTML+CSS with Javascript manipulating the DOM.  Interaction is furthered with AJAX.

That doesn't negate the use of Java however.  Typically all of your business logic will still be done on the server side, often in a Java servlet which services request from the front end.

So yes, in general the Web is moving away from Web apps with the UI implemented as a Java applet, but Java is stronger than ever in its role for the Web app market.

Comment: Ok, using Java server-side is an important piece I hadn't fully considered. It would probably be preferable in my situation, so thanks for bringing that up.

Comment: Also, you mention the "web app market". I was doing some digging and came across a Mozilla Labs post (http://blog.mozilla.com/blog/2010/10/19/prototype-of-an-open-web-app-ecosystem/). Google labs has a similar thing going (http://code.google.com/chrome/apps/docs/index.html). My previous understanding was that "web app" was a more trendy synonym for "fancy AJAX webpage." However, my definitions are now more blurred than ever. Does anyone have any additional resources? I'm trying to get a handle on what will be the best long-term plan for developing and deploying this (and future) applications.

Comment: @zourtney: I wouldn't narrow the definition.  A web app is an application served over the web.  Maybe narrow that to an application reached through a browser.  "Web 2.0 app" would typically refer to an AJAX-y page.